# Connecting Android webservices to localhost

Tags: android, web-services, localhost

I am fighting with this particular thing but not able to resolve it.. Please help me...
I am trying to connect the android program to a local host which is running on apache server.

I found examples in internet which directly connect to their own websites. So, they are giving the name spaces(in the following program) with their name spaces. 
But since I have my web application in my local host, what should I mention?

(I am pasting my code here)
MainActivity.java

```
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private String METHOD_NAME = "sum"; // our webservice method name
    private String NAMESPACE = "http://calculator.backend.web.org&#8221"; //I have to give the name space here I guess
    private String SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE + METHOD_NAME; 
    private static final String URL = "http://localhost:8081/Test/services/Caluclate?wsdl"; 

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtAddition);
    try
    {
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        request.addProperty("i", 5);
        request.addProperty("j", 15);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION,envelope);
        Object result = envelope.getResponse();
        System.out.println(" Result : "  + result.toString());
        ((TextView) findViewById (R.id.txtAddition)).setText("Addition : "+result.toString());
        } catch (Exception E) {
            E.printStackTrace();
            ((TextView) findViewById (R.id.txtAddition)).setText("Error: "   + E.getClass().getName() + ":" + E.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Calculate.java(program in the web app)

```
public class Caluclate {
    public int sum() {
         return (1);
   }
   public int subtract(int i, int j) {
         return (i - j);
   }
   public int multiply(int i, int j) {
         return (i * j);
   }
   public int divide(int i, int j) {
         return (i / j);
   }
}
```

Thank you for helping me...

Comment: localhost replace by 127.0.0.1 or 10.0.2.2

Answer (score 1):

I assume the service endpoint is running on a remote machine but not directly on the mobile device.

In this case localhost would not work because it is a local alias for 127.0.0.1 which resolves to itself.

In your code at the moment,  every device will try to reach services hosted by itself.  You have to replace `localhost` by the ip of the server hosting the endpoint

Comment: Hi thanks for replying. I followed your suggestion. I tried 127.0.0.1 and 10.0.2.2 and my system ip address too.. but still no luck. And the error is being shown at SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,METHOD_NAME);

Comment: hi @BaradwajAryasomayajula, where is you service physically hosted?

Comment: Hi @Jmorvan I am storing the data in the database using mysql and jsp in my local host itself.

Comment: ok, per what you said it seems the ip address of your host is 10.0.2.2 this is what you should use (if it hasnt changed) to connect to your service. if this didnt work, it's probably a firewall issue. check that port 8081 (the port you use) is open for incomming traffic.

Comment: No. It did not work.. So I moved on and using the parse.com for storing the data in the cloud and extracting it in my mobile

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
private static final String URL = "http:// 10.0.2.2:8081/Test/services/Caluclate?wsdl";
```

Answer (score 0):

hi friend find your PC allocated IP (Go to CMD and type ipconfig and find IP address) replace  "Localhost" with that IP Address .this works for me.